# sum of one row's ( two column's avg value ) and that very same row's (another column's value)

Tags: mysql, rdbms

[image: This is the table I've created, name of table is elaborate_result]

I've written a query but it's showing error. I want to get the AVG of `mid_1_english` and `mid_2_english` and then want to add that AVG with `semester_final_english`.

```
select s_roll_no, s_f_name, s_l_name, s_class, 
           SUM(mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 as mid_english, 
           SUM(mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 as mid_mathematics, 
           SUM(mid_english + semester_final_english) as total_english, 
           SUM(mid_mathematics + semester_final_mathematics) as total_mathematics 
from elaborate_result 
group by s_f_name, s_l_name;
LIMIT 0, 50000
```

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'mid_english' in 'field list' 0.000
>   sec

Comment: update your question with fiddle link and entire error message

Comment: Edit your question and add the error message + more information. This should not go in the comments

Comment: check your column_name mid_english

Comment: `mid_english` is not a column of table `elaborate_result`. Fix this first and come back

Comment: I'm storing the avg of mid_1_english and mid_2_english in mid_english, The question doesn't even arise if I fix this. Go through the question another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do something like this

```
    Select SUM(mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 as mid_english
```

It doesn't create a new column mid_english . So you can not use it as a column in the same query.

So what you need will probably look something like this

```
    select s_roll_no, s_f_name, s_l_name, s_class, 
       SUM(mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 as mid_english, 
       SUM(mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 as mid_mathematics, 
       SUM((mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 + semester_final_english) as 
     total_english, 
      SUM((mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 + 
     semester_final_mathematics) as total_mathematics 
    from elaborate_result 
  group by s_f_name, s_l_name;
 LIMIT 0, 50000
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the exact solution I've been looking for